# what is the yellow/tan thin crust on both of ceramic pot holding an indoor palm plant

Tags: houseplants, indoors

I have a large palm plant in my office in a ceramic pot which drains into a matching ceramic dish.

Recently, a thin yellow or tan crust have formed on the planter right at the bottom. I can remove it with a cloth.

Is this from overwatering, the soil or the water I am using?

Comment: It sounds like deposition of calcium salts, which were present in the water and/or soil. But a picture would be very helpful. Do you have much calcium in your water?

Comment: A photo would be very helpful - it doesn't sound like calcium or lime deposits if you can wipe it off easily with a cloth

Comment: You could probably wipe off mineral deposits if they never get to completely dry out. We don't know exactly what "right at the bottom" means, and how the plant is being watered.

Comment: Susan, welcome! As the others have commented, a photo and a few more details could help. Please [edit] your post to help us help you. The [tour] and [help] will explain more about the site while you wait for an answer.